# Litecoin binary for Linux

Tags: litecoin, linux, compiling

Is there any LiteCoin binary precompiled for Linux?

I would prefer staticaly linked but would also dynamicaly linked a try.

A plus is given for a .deb archive, two pluses for a ppa or other possibility to integrate it into ubuntu 11.10 packagemanagement.

Comment: In the meantime I figured out how to compile this one, I will try to repeat the necessary steps in the next days on a clean Ubuntu install and post a step by step explanation here.

Comment: https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/downloads ctrl-f 'linux'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm trying to close some old questions.)

Litecoin has a Linux download button on it's [homepage](http://litecoin.org/) now.

As Nick Odell [pointed out](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2268/litecoin-binary-for-linux#comment9729_2268), you can also find the downloads on [GitHub](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/downloads).